# SMS sending working in 2.2 Froyo but not in ICS 4.0

Tags: android, sms, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am developing an App which sends SMS and receives some response.

Now the problem is that the SMS sending works fine in 2.2 froyo but its not working in ICS 4.0.

I have done the following in my code:

1. added the permission in my Manifest tp receive and send SMS.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
   ```
2. Here is the code i am using in the a Button to send SMS.

   ```
   public void sendSms(String phoneNumber,String sms) {      
       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
       smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null ,sms,  null, null);            
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you using `android.telephony.SmsManager` or `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager` ?

Comment: +1 for @soulreaver comment. Also, have you tried catching the result code? Maybe could help you understanding what is happening.

Comment: i am using this one import android.telephony.SmsManager;